# Program complexity

Tags: computational-complexity

We have a two-dimensional $n \times n$ array containing binary values
binary ($0$ and $1$) where $0$ denotes a black pixel and $1$ a white pixel.

Enter the number of square areas (with the same number of columns and rows), in of which there are as many black pixels as white pixels. For example, found the $2 \times 2$ area should have two cells containing white and two pixels containing black pixels. However, a $10 \times 10$ area was correctly found should have $50$ white pixels and the same number of black ones. The program should provide for given array, the number of different square areas of any size for which the same number of cells containing 1 as the containing cells were found number $0$.

Calculate the computational complexity of two versions of the program:

- not using the partial sum table
- using a partial sum table created earlier

The partial sum table stores in the position (k, l) the sum of the analyzed elements
array contained in cells (i, j) for which i<=n, j<=m (in cells located on
left and top of the cell with the address (k, l)). Therefore, to determine the sum of S elements in
In the rectangular area of ​​the table, just refer to the four values ​​from the sum table

partial parts according to the formula: S = D + A-B-C

Comment: What's the problem?  The simple program is linear in the number of pixels queried.

Comment: I do not know how to write it from the mathematical side to set it.

Comment: A linear function is written ${\cal O}(n)$, where $n$ is the number of pixels queried.

Comment: I am not talking about the result itself but about the way in which it is calculated

Comment: I urge you to read any basic text or website on computational complexity.  I cannot imagine a simpler problem in that domain than this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my field, so please help me solve this task. Thank you for reply.